# 301 redirect custom link

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have few thousands link like this

```
/Gallery?cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=3747&pgID=1
```

Now I want to redirect them using .htaccess to another site to others link. Every will link will be redirect to its own destination link. I tried like this

```
Redirect 301 /Gallery?cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=3747&pgID=1 http://example.com/gallery/fcar_gallery
```

But not working. I have enable mod_rewrite in my server and olther redirect is working perfectly.

Comment: you cannot use redirect for that, use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Querystring is not part of match in Redirect directive, to redirect query strings, you need to use mod-rewrite as follows :

**option 1**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Gallery\?cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=3747&pgID=1  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/gallery/fcar_gallery? [NC,L,R]
```

**option 2**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=3747&pgID=1  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/gallery/fcar_gallery? [NC,L,R]
```

We use an empty question mark **?** at the end of the target url to discard the old query strings, otherwise these query strings get appened to the target url by default.

Change the **R** to **R=301** if you want to make the redirection permanent.

[Tested on apache2 and 2.4]